# How to calculate mean in group by another group?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, group-by, mean

I have a dataframe:

```
    date                    id       type        revenue
0 2021-09-01                Zw        b1         20.045350
1 2021-09-01                Aw        c          8.990000
2 2021-09-01                Zc        c          14.990000
3 2021-09-01                ww        b          25.944510
4 2021-09-01                jw        c          3.881649
5 2021-09-01                pw        b          9.990000
6 2021-09-01                fg        c          2.990000
7 2021-09-01                kl        b          4.990000
8 2021-09-02                mm        b          7.990000
```

I want to calculate mean revenue for each type, but not in group of type but in group of date. So for example mean type "b1" must be not 20.045350 (since there is only one b1 type) but 20.045350/8 = 2.5 (since there are 8 2021-09-01 values in column date). So desired result must be:

```
    date                    type      revenue
0 2021-09-01                b1        2.5
0 2021-09-01                c         3.85
0 2021-09-01                b         5.11
0 2021-09-02                b         7.990000
```

How to do that? groupby("date", "type").mean() brings wrong results:

```
    date                    type      revenue
0 2021-09-01                b1        20.045
0 2021-09-01                c         7.71
0 2021-09-01                b         13.64
0 2021-09-02                b         7.990000
```

Comment: how is the second one 3.85? Can you explain that? and can you also explain the 5.11?

Comment: @Onyambu 3.85 comes from (8.99+14.99+3.88+2.99)/8 . 8 is number of rows in date group 2021-09-01

Comment: `df.groupby('date')['id'].count().reset_index().rename({'id':'count'}, axis = 1).merge(df).pipe(lambda x: x.assign(revenue = x.revenue/x['count'])).groupby(['date','type']).agg({'revenue':sum}).reset_index()`

Comment: @Onyambu it didn't calculate results for  2021-09-02 group

Comment: I posted the anser. It does calculate the results of 2021-09-02. I do not know what you mean. Check the answer I posted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df1 = df.groupby('date')['id'].count().reset_index().\
             rename({'id':'count'}, axis = 1).merge(df)

df2 = df1.assign(revenue = df1.revenue/df1['count']).groupby(['date','type']).\
            agg({'revenue':sum}).reset_index()

df2 
         date type   revenue
0  2021-09-01    b  5.115564
1  2021-09-01   b1  2.505669
2  2021-09-01    c  3.856456
3  2021-09-02    b  7.990000
```

---

A fancy way of doing the same will be:

```
df.groupby('date')['id'].count().reset_index().rename({'id':'count'}, axis = 1).merge(df).\
   pipe(lambda x: x.assign(revenue = x.revenue/x['count'])).groupby(['date','type']).\
   agg({'revenue':sum}).reset_index()
```

Answer (score 0):

Do a double groupby and divide them :

```py
(df.groupby(['type', 'date'])
   .revenue
   .sum()
   .div(df.date.value_counts(), level='date')
)
type  date
b     2021-09-01    5.115564
      2021-09-02    7.990000
b1    2021-09-01    2.505669
c     2021-09-01    3.856456
dtype: float64
```

Explanation :

- Get the counts for the dates:

```py
counts = df.date.value_counts()
```

- Get the sum for the revenue, based on `type` and `date`:

```py
revenue_sum =  df.groupby(['type', 'date']).revenue.sum()
```

Divide `revenue_sum` by `counts`, using the `date` level:

```py
revenue_sum.div(counts, level='date')

type  date
b     2021-09-01    5.115564
      2021-09-02    7.990000
b1    2021-09-01    2.505669
c     2021-09-01    3.856456
dtype: float64
```